# Dropdown from sheetfile to html form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm looking how transfer data from a sheet to a dropdown in a form using Google Script.
Here's a guide I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKksZpsuJJM
It's mostly interesting at 9:38

Here's my code:

**GS**

```
// Return a string array, no problem here
function getUniqueCustomers() {
  return customerData;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="filterForm">

      <label for="customerFilter">Customer</label><br/>
      <select name="customerFilter" id="customerFilter">
      </select><br/><br/>
</form>

<script>
    function afterFormLoad() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDropdownArrayReturned).getUniqueCustomers();
      }

      function afterDropdownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays) {
        var customer = document.getElementById("customer");
        arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.textContent = r[0];
          //option.value = r[0];
          //option.id = r[0];
          customer.appendChild(option);
        });
      }

      document.addEventlistener("DOMContentLoaded", afterFormLoad);
    </script>
```

I've spent too much time on this function.
Thanks a lot for your answers

PS: It's my second post on the subject but with a new code. I made a repost because I hope to have a quick answer. I will delete the other post when this one will be resolved.

Comment: You can do it using scriplets and loading the html server side by creating a template use evaluate to load data, otherwise you will have to initiate the action from the html.

Comment: Since you are watching a youtube guide anyway, have you actually tried at least implementing ````getDropDownArray()```` in your code? Or at least post what error are you getting? Please check how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to initialize the action from the form with the onOpen() function Nothing appends.
The problem is that the function afterFormLoad() is not called.

Yes, it doesn't change something.
I'm not getting any error messages. The fact is that the select is empty

Comment: How is your ````customerData```` defined and populated? As is, this variable is empty so even if ````afterFormLoad()```` is called it will not append any rows.

Comment: I have a script that builds forms from sheets for teaching. It builds most types and has other features. see the sidebar instructions for notes. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Amy8LgeCdl8RsDr98pEVXVSqrMzGqMc_VuLYQy94mC8/edit?usp=sharing